# Importance of number of Swaps in analysis of the sorting algorithm - Three-Way Partitioning

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting, quicksort

I'm developing a *Three-Way partitioning* algorithm for sorting the data. I could observe that for few distinct elements in large data set the number of comparison made by algorithm is less than traditional version of Quick-sort.

However, the number of swaps taken are higher than normal version of quick-sort.

In order to perform the analysis of the algorithm I need to understand what is the impact of number of swaps and comparisons on overall algorithm performance.

Comment: in practice, swapping elements is vastly more expensive than comparing. This is even more pronounced when elements are far apart, due to caching. So, on modern hardware, algorithms that tend to swap less - and when they do swap, move elements the furthest towards their final destination - tend to win out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When analysing the efficiency of an algorithm by [static analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_analysis) - that is, without actually running the code and measuring the time it takes - we are usually concerned only with the [asymptotic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory) of the algorithm, which can be described using [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) and related asymptotic notations.

One important fact about big O notation is that O(*f* + *g*) is either O(*f*) or O(*g*), whichever is larger. So if *f* measures how many comparisons your algorithm makes, and *g* measures how many swaps, then whichever is larger will be the important one. Both have an impact on the algorithm's *actual* running time, but only the larger one has an impact on the *asymptotic* running time.

Most sorting algorithms do more comparisons than swaps, so normally the number of comparisons is what matters. But if your algorithm does more swaps than comparisons, then the number of swaps is what matters for your algorithm.

Of course, if there are other operations your algorithm does, like addition, multiplication, reading or allocating memory allocation, then you should consider these too. Whichever operation your algorithm does most is what would determine its asymptotic running time.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. The current algorithm developed by me has following observations   - In the case if very few distinct elements the number of comparison are less than that of normal quicksort but the swaps are considerably higher. In my version the number of comparisons and swaps are comparable as they have similar value (comparison are larger than swaps though). So for my analysis I would need to add comparison and swaps to find overall complexity. Is that correct?

Comment: If your algorithm sometimes does more swaps and sometimes does more comparisons, then you should add them together, yes. But this only happens because you're considering the average case, the worst case and the best case all at once. If you analyse just the average case, then either the average number of swaps has to be higher or the average number of comparisons has to be higher. Then you can analyse the worst case separately.